# Como mudar a mensagem de um commit enviado para o repositório remoto

Tags: git

Fiz 3 commits no repositório local e enviei para o repositório remoto utilizando o `push`.

Reparei que a mensagem de um dos commits estava errada. Como faço para mudar a mensagem nas seguintes condições:

1. O commit já foi enviado para o repositório remoto;
2. Um programador atualizou o repositório local com o commit errado.
3. Outro programador atualizou o repositório local e logo a seguir fez um novo commit atualizando o repositório remoto.
4. Outro programador também atualizou o repositório local, fez um novo commit mas não atualizou o repositório remoto.

Ou seja:

```
1. Repositóro remoto 
       o--->A--->B--->C

2. Programador X
       o--->A--->B--->C

3. Programador Y
       o--->A--->B--->C--->D
   Repositóro remoto 
       o--->A--->B--->C--->D

4. Programador Z
       o--->A--->B--->C--->E
   Repositóro remoto 
       o--->A--->B--->C--->D
```

Supondo que o commit com a mensagem errada é o `B`, como corrigir a mensagem?

Comment: Não tem como você corrigir, a única alternativa seria se ninguém tivesse feito o `pull`, você poderia corrigir localmente e fazer um `push force`, o que não é legal porque muda totalmente a história do repositório e os outros usuários teriam problemas

Comment: @Gerep Então o que é recomendado fazer? Um commit com uma mensagem errada também pode ser problemática.

Comment: Você pode tentar usar o comando `git revert`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

Você não vai conseguir fazer esse commit desaparecer, só corrigir o que foi feito, o histórico vai fica aí =(

Answer (score 1):

Como foi colocado nos comentários, a solução drástica seria você fazer o reset para o commit imediatamente anterior, com o comando:

```
git reset --hard <commit>
git push --force
```

Mas lembre-se: **TODO** o histórico após esse commit será perdido para sempre.

Caso você queira, também pode fazer o comando revert, que elimina o commit sem desfazer o histório. Para isso, basta usar o comando

```
git revert <commit>
git push
```

Mas esse comando perderá o conteúdo do teu commit, mas não afetará o histórico depois dele.

Comment: Mas se o revert elimina o conteúdo do commit, como fica então as alterações que foram realizadas nesse commit? Tenho que refazê-las? Não há maneira no Git de inserir uma nota, por exemplo, deixando a mensagem original, porém com uma nota de correção, ou algo do gênero?

Comment: Como foi dito nos outros comentários. Não há maneira de você alterar só a mensagem do commit ou alterar o conteúdo de um só arquivo desse mesmo commit ou mesmo o horário do commit. Essas operações são atômicas. Você poderia refazer a alteração que constava nesse commit em outro, com a mensagem correta.